# trying to set status in bash function

Tags: bash

I have these 2 functions on bash;

```
function ask_yes_or_no() {
    read -p "$1 ([y]es or [N]o): "
    case $(echo $REPLY | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]') in
        y|yes) echo "yes" ;;
        *)     echo "no" ;;
    esac
}
```

and

```
    function is_it_installed()
{
    i=0; n=0; progs=($@);
    for p in "${progs[@]}"; do
        if hash "$p" &>/dev/null
        then
            echo "$p is installed"
            let c++
        else
            echo "'$p' is not installed. Do you want to install '$p'"
            if [[ "yes" == $(ask_yes_or_no "Are you sure?") ]]
            then
                apt-get install $p
            else
                echo="Skipped installation of: '$p'"
                # exit 1
            fi
            let n++
        fi
    done
    printf "%d of %d programs were installed.\n"  "$i" "${#progs[@]}" 
    printf "%d of %d programs were missing\n" "$n" "${#progs[@]}"
}
```

And I call this from another bashscript. But I would like to be able to set a status (or similar) to check if for example "mail" is installed, then "mail"s status should be 1, which I then can use in another check in the script using the function; something like this:

```
if [mail = 1]; then
do something
else something else
fi
```

Comment: `[` is a command. Commands are separated from their arguments with spaces. You can't run `[mail` instead of `[ mail` any more than you can run `lsfoo.txt` instead of `ls foo.txt`

Comment: ...and if you're only targeting bash 4.0 or later, `case ${REPLY,,} in` is a lot faster than spinning up a subshell with a pipeline running `tr`.

Comment: (There are also a bunch of quoting issues -- consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before asking questions here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could run `which mail` which should give you the path of the package installed. For example:

`which bash`
`/usr/local/bin/bash`

so you could check if the return of `which bash` is 0 or not using `$?` If it is 0 then the package is installed

Comment: `which` is relatively expensive, as it's an external command, not part of the shell. `if command -v bash >/dev/null 2>&1; then` is guaranteed to be both present and fast (built-in, not an external executable) on all POSIX-compliant shells.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `return` statement in your function. `return 0` means success and `return 1` (or any integer between 1 and 255) is an error.

You can test with `if`:

```
if func_name
then
    # func_name was successful
else
    # func_name was unsuccessful
    echo $?     # actual returned number
fi
```

You could:

```
func_name
if (( $? == 1 ))
then
    ...
fi
```

but that can be messed up easily, so the first pattern is better.  `$?` is the exit or return status of the previous command.